firebase not working after build tauri application
I'm currently working on a Tauri project where I integrated Firebase for user authentication. While everything works perfectly on localhost, I encountered an issue after building my application.
When I create a .deb file for installation, and subsequently install the application, Firebase stops functioning. Specifically, I'm unable to create an account or log in, as the authentication processes fail.
Have you experienced similar issues, or do you have any insights on why Firebase might not work in the built version of a Tauri app? Any suggestions on debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Does this help? https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/4805
